# Limit find $f(x)$ $ \lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}}}{\sqrt[3]x-1}=3 $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Given
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}}}{\sqrt[3]x-1}=3
$$

How can I find $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ ? I cant figure out a way to simplify $\cos$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $y^3-1=(y-1)(y^2+y+1),$

$$3=-\frac\pi2\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\cdot\frac{\sin\left[\frac\pi2(1-x)\right]}{\frac\pi2(1-x)}\cdot(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]x+1)$$

Comment: It seems the key was there to change cos to sin. I should have thought it...

Comment: @Parhs, Yes as we can use $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* $\;\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f(x)\;$ exists, you can use arithmetic of limits:

$$3=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)\cos\frac{\pi x}2}{\sqrt[3]x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cos\frac{\pi x}2}{\sqrt[3]x-1}$$

The rightmost limit is, using l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{-\frac\pi2\sin\frac{\pi x}2}{\frac13x^{-2/3}}=-\frac32\pi$$

End now the exercise.

Comment: hm yep, however I have added without l'Hospital tag. Any idea there ?

Comment: Without l'H? Well, look at the other answer. A nice idea there. Yet I can't understand why without l'H as this, when appliable, makes things so much easier many times. Oh, well.

Comment: Just solving some before LHospital problems and want to learn without it too...

Comment: @Parhs I see. Good idea then as doing it without l'H can enhance one's algebraic/trigonometric/exponential skills, but later...

Answer (score 0):

First step is to find
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cos\frac{\pi x}2}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}.$$
Since you have tagged this as without using L'Hopital, use the substitution $x=y^3$ and note $y\to1$ as $x\to1$, so:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cos\frac{\pi x}2}{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}=\lim_{y\to1}\frac{\cos\frac{\pi y^3}2}{y-1}=\frac{d}{dy}\cos\tfrac{\pi y^3}2\bigg|_{y=1}=-\frac{3\pi y^2}2\sin\tfrac{\pi y^3}2\bigg|_{y=1}=-\frac{3\pi}2.$$
Then use arithmetic of limits.

Comment: Without l'H but using derivatives? I'm not sure how sound this could be...

Comment: I don't think assuming basic calculus is unreasonable, and the second limit is just the definition of the derivative. Using L'Hopital may seem dodgy if you have never seen a proof.

Comment: l'Hospital is also pretty basic calculus, and I can't imagine someone doing a first *decent* calculus course without it. Yet I've seen many times the requirement "without l'Hospital". If the goal is to develop *other* mathematical skills to solve I am for it, otherwise it can just make simple things cumbersome.

Comment: Sure, but I can imagine a point early-ish in a calculus course where you have been taught differentiation and limit laws but not yet reached L'Hopital when such a question could appear.